# How to label only one point in tmap in r?

Tags: r, label, tmap, spatial-data

In the example below I would like to have only the label for Ghana in the `tm_text("name")` layer showing.

Any idea how to do this?
Thank you for your help.

```
library(tmap)
data("World")
tmap_mode("view")

tm_shape(World) +
  tm_polygons("HPI", id="HPI")+tm_text("name")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give you what you require:
The key line is: `tm_shape(filter(World, name == "Ghana"))` which uses `dplyr::filter()` to subset the `name` variable for the required name(s).
With Ghana outlined in red to make it more obvious which country the label refers to.

```r
library(tmap)
library(dplyr)

data("World")


tm_shape(World) +
  tm_polygons("HPI", id="HPI")+
  tm_shape(filter(World, name == "Ghana")) +
  tm_borders(col = "red")+
  tm_text("name", xmod = -1, ymod = -1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>